# Images of some content types disappeared

Tags: 7, files

I have something strange going on on one of my drupal installation.

It seem's that for two content types all the images got unlinked from the existing entities. I can still see in the table `file_managed` that the images are still in database and linked to the entity and the files are also on disk. But when I edit an entity of those two content types the images do not show up. I can only upload a new one.

Has somebody ever experienced this kind of issue? What could I check to see what caused this strange behavior? Beside me 3 other content editors have access to the drupal admin panel. What could they have done so that the pictures of all entities for two content types disappeared overnight?

**EDIT** I just noticed other fields are als gone. All the data is still in database but does not show up in either edit form/node view.

Comment: What do you see when you edit the content type definition? eg: /admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields

Comment: @R.Durham the fields are there and now contain data again. Very strange hickup. Now everythings back again :-O. Maybe more an issue of the hoster then of drupal ?

Comment: Yeah there may have been a problem with the database or the SQL server.